# Unable to upload file (size greater than 50KB) using Jquery hosted on apache httpd server

Tags: jquery

Scenarios:

1. I am able to upload files successfully which are less then 50 kb.
2. Anything greater then 50 kb the request does not reach the server itself(My  observation).
3. All GET  requests are working fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('ngFiles', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  function fn_link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var onChange = $parse(attrs.ngFiles);
    element.on('change', function(event) {
      onChange(scope, {
        $files: event.target.files
      });
    });
  };

  return {
    link: fn_link
  }
}]).controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  var formdata = new FormData();
  $scope.getTheFiles = function($files) {
    angular.forEach($files, function(value, key) {
      formdata.append(key, value);
    });
  };

  // NOW UPLOAD THE FILES.
  $scope.uploadFiles = function() {
    var request = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/fileupload/',
      data: formdata,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
      }
    };

    // SEND THE FILES.
    $http(request).success(function(d) {
      // Some Logic
    }).catch(function(Object) {
      // Some Logic
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This sounds like a server configuration issue, not a JS one. I'd suggest you amend your hosting platform.

Comment: Check maxUploadSize value of your config file.

Comment: Its my bad, actually my service is running with my user, but I file had root user permission. When I changed file permission as chown -R myuser:myuser filename.pdf, then it worked. less than 50kb file which I mentioned was created by me, since that file had my user permission so it was working fine. Sometime such a silly things screw our enough time. we feel embarrassing when we realize our silly mistakes :) Anyways thanks @RoryMcCrossan